# AngularJS extract dynamic matching data from JSON

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a dynamic complex JSON, something like this

```
 var source = [{
        "ab" : 123,    
        "xfg" : {
            "cdf" : "xyz",
            "e" : [{"aaa" : "bbb"}, {"ccc" : "ccc"}]
        },
        "mno" : ["fff", "123"]
    }];
```

How can I extract data from this JSON using some dynamic expressions in a given search object:

```
var search= {
    "search1" : "ab",
    "search2" : "xfg.cdf",  
    "search3" : "ccc value in xfg.e?",  
}
```

Basically, I can analyze the type of each element in the search object, if it's a string split it by '.' separator and then access the elements in the source object...
But what about complex search expressions? How do I get the 'ccc' value for example?. Is there a way to implement complex search expressions? something like in mongodb find function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this, but the demo looks really nice. It's basically a css type selector for JSON: [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#tryit).

For a more XPath style, try JSONPath, which also looks very capable. [JSONPath](https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath)

Both are Javascript libraries and are easily included in your project.

Comment: It seems very interesting! i'm looking at theses resources, thank u :)